# Python IndexError: list index out of range (2D list)

Tags: python, list, index-error

I am new to python and currently testing out 2d lists.

This program uses a 2d list to store the sales of 3 types of noodle for each day in a week.

Also, in every day, there will also be a column that stores the total sales per day.

However, I am getting an IndexError where I can't seem to figure out what went wrong.

```
Sales = [[]]

def enterSales(arr):

    i = 0
    j = 0
    total_per_day = 0

    while i < 7:

        day = {
            0: "Monday",
            1: "Tuesday",
            2: "Wednesday",
            3: "Thursday",
            4: "Friday",
            5: "Saturday",
            6: "Sunday"
        }

        print("Enter " + day[i] + " sales for...")

        for j in range(3):

            noodle = {
                0: "Dried",
                1: "Dark",
                2: "Spicy",
            }

            arr[i].append(int(input(noodle[j] + " noodle: ")))

            # calculate total sales per day
            total_per_day += arr[i][j]

        arr[i].append(total_per_day)
        i += 1


def totalWeeklySales(arr):

    total_sales_per_week = 0

    for i in range(7):

        total_sales_per_week += arr[i][3]

    return total_sales_per_week


enterSales(Sales)
value = totalWeeklySales(Sales)
print("Total sales of the week is", value, ".")
```

[image]

Comment: What you are doing is declaring `Sales = [[]]` which is like have a list with 1 list item. As a result, it will store the values for the 1st day but won't have another child list to store the items for the 2nd day onward. What you will need is to append a list to `arr` before you start accepting the sales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop you have to add empty list for each `i` loop.

add below line before incrementing `i`

```
arr[i].append(total_per_day) # after this line in your code
arr.append([])  #add this line
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in your Sales list.
On each itration you are trying to append a new element to the i'th list in **Sales**:

`arr[i].append(int(input(noodle[j] + " noodle: ")))`

Since you have `Sales=[[],]` in the beginning. The first iteration (i = 0) works just fine. The problem occurs on the second one when it is trying to access Sales[1] -> out of range because Sales has only 1 element.

Since you have 7 iterations (`while i < 7`). You can initialize your sales as follows:

`Sales = [[] for x in range(7)]`

Which will result in `Sales=[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]`.

I'd also suggest you to put 7 in some constant so it is clearer what it means and you could reuse it.